# What time period during daytime is known as Vinda?

Tags: ramayana, astrology

In Ramayana, Jatayu at the time of his death [stated](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga68/aranya_68_frame.htm) the following

> "In which spell of time Ravana has gone taking away Seetha, that spell is named as Vinda... if any riches are lost during that spell, the original possessor of those riches will repossess them very quickly... oh, Kakutstha, he that Ravana is unmindful of that fact and stole Seetha only to loose her... [3-68-12, 13a]

The link further mentions that there are 15 spells of time at daytime and they have their own effects on humans.And Vinda also known as Vijaya is the 11th spell. Any action initiated in this spell of the day entails adverse effects, in so far as that aim and action of the initiator.

So which period in day time does the period Vinda correspond to? Does it change during the course of the year ?

Answer (score 2):

Vinda happens to be the **11th muhurta** of the day, and is considered an inauspicious time period.

First the definition of *muhurta* from [Manusmriti 1.64](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145490.html)

> Ten and eight ‘nimeṣas’ (should be known as) one ‘Kāṣṭhā’; thirty such (Kāṣṭhās) one ‘Kalā’; thirty ‘Kalās’ one ‘muhūrta’; and as many ‘muhūrtas’ one ‘Ahorātra’ (Day and Night).—(64)

So from above 30 *muhurtas* make a day. Now if we take 24 hours in a day, each muhurta will be 48 minutes long. Now Vinda (also known as *Vahini* translates to "Possessed of chariot") muhurta starts 10*48 minutes after sunrise and lasts for 48 minutes. (Src [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhurta)) - but will try and update it from acceptable sources

EDIT
But 48 minutes is not set in stone. If time between two sunrises is let's say 24 hrs 30 minutes, then each muhurta would be 49 minutes long

Comment: Good information.  According to Hinduism, the 24 hours time will be reckoned from Sunrise to Sunrise.  So the 11th muhurta starts after 8 hours from Sunrise.  So Sita might have been abducted between 2.00 pm to 2.48 pm :-)

Comment: That is correct if sunrise is exactly at 6 am everyday as I assumed in above answer. But I think 48 minutes is not constant. If sunrise is at 6 today and tomorrow 6:30, then each muhurta would be 49 minutes long